# Soundcloud Custom player only for soundcloud?

Tags: soundcloud

Is the custom player only for soundcloud mp3's, or is it possible to use the player for any project, like playing your own mp3 files from your server.

Thanks
Pascal

Answer (score 2):

In order to play audio using the Soundcloud player, you have to create a Soundcloud account & upload your music to your "own" account.

But you can actually customize your player if this so happens to be what you mean. By connecting to a Soundcloud API which then returns data from Soundcloud, which then. You use CSS/ to style your output results.

Hope I could help.

Answer (score 1):

It can only work with audio on SoundCloud.